# Grouping components to form a complete perimeter

Tags: image-processing, image

This is a question relating to grouping of components picked out using ComponentMeasurements to make a complete perimeter of a shape. My goal is to measure the perimeter of each of these worm-like particles, and to plot a histogram distribution of it.

[image: Particles]

From ComponentMeasurements, I would be able to obtain the perimeter of each particle that I need for the histogram. I used EdgeDetect and filtered out noise to obtain a relatively good result for ComponentMeasurements.

```
picEdge2 = RemoveBackground[DeleteBorderComponents[Image[EdgeDetect[pic, 6.6]]]];
array = ComponentMeasurements[picEdge2, {"Shape", "PerimeterLength", "Mask", 
 "MinimalBoundingBox", "BoundingBox"}, #Width > 10 && #PerimeterLength > 50 && #PerimeterLength < 1400 &] // Values;
```

[image: ComponentMeasurements result]

This seems to work pretty well, and I have complete perimeters for most particles.
[image: Complete Particles]

However, the perimeter of some worms have been broken up into different pieces, such as in the following picture (red and yellow are different components).

[image: Incomplete Perimeter]

I have tried grouping components together by testing whether their bounding boxes or minimal bounding boxes intersect - however, this tends to group together multiple neighboring particles instead, because the particles are too close together.

```
IntersectQ[a_, b_] := Area[RegionIntersection[Polygon[{a[[1]], a[[2]],
a[[3]], a[[4]]}], Polygon[{b[[1]], b[[2]], b[[3]], b[[4]]}]]] > 0
```

Instead, I was thinking of trying to convert from the mask or shape obtained from ComponentMeasurements into a ConvexHull, and test for an intersection between ConvexHulls of each component. However, I'm not too sure how I should go about converting from a mask to points (so that I can make a ConvexHull), or if this method is feasible. What would be the best way to group components to ensure a complete perimeter, without grouping multiple particles together?

Thank you!